# Sorting query results according to parent property in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is it possible in grails to sort query results according to a property of a parent class in a relationship. E.g. I have a user domain class which has a one to many relationship with a list of Tasks.

When showing the list page of the Tasks domain class, I want to be able to sort the list of tasks by the associated User name.

```
class User {
    String name
    String login
    String group
    List tasks = new ArrayList()
    static hasMany = [tasks:Task]
}

class Task {
    String summary
    String details
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

I can do something like this

```
Task.list([sort:"user", order:"asc"])
```

But this sorts by the user.id, is there a way to specify the sort to be on the user.name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using [Criteria](http://www.grails.org/Hibernate+Criteria+Builder)

```
def criteria = Task.createCriteria()
def taskList = criteria.list {
    createAlias("user","_user")
    order( "_user.name")
}
```

Comment: Cool, works like a charm. Any idea how I can make the sorting case insensitive?

Comment: Never mind, found it on hibernate docs, apparently i just add .ignoreCase() to the order like this
order("_user.name").ignoreCase()

Comment: this however doesn't work in terms of setting the default sort order for the object, which seems to be a royal pain in the ass.

Comment: What was the purpose of creating the alias?

Answer (score 0):

iirc, grails sorts by using toString() and since you have not supplied one, it uses the id.