# findAll order by "many to one" column raises exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an entity, Student, defined in Student.groovy as:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ['id'])
class Student {

    Long id
    String name
    String type

    University university     

    static mapping = {
         university column : 'UNIVERSITY_ID'
    } 

}
```

and a University entity, defined in University.groovy as:

```
class University {
     Long id
     String name

     static mapping = {
         id column : 'id', generator : 'assigned'
     }
}
```

I've been trying to switch from calling

```
Student.list(sort: ..., order: ...)
```

to calling:

```
Student.findAll("from Student s where type = :type ", [type : 'T'], [ sort : 'name' ])
```

This fails to order correctly by the name field. The previous version, using `list` worked fine.

I've also tried calling something like

```
Student.findAll(sort : 'name') { type == "T" }
```

which worked fine like this, but when trying to sort by the university.name

```
Student.findAll(sort : 'university.name') { type == 'T" }
```

it raised an error regarding the university.name field not being found.

Anybody have any idea on how to do this properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post `University` domain??

Comment: Yes, sure, I added the definition in the question body. Thanx.

Comment: Take a look at this answer about sorting by association: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594301/sorting-query-results-according-to-parent-property-in-grails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `executeQuery` instead of `findAll` - they should function the same, but I've found that `executeQuery` is for some reason a more direct caller of the HQL, and `findAll` fails or returns unexpected results in some cases.

So that first query would be

```
Student.executeQuery(
   'select s from Student s where s.type = :type order by s.name',
   [type : 'T'])
```

and ordering by university name would be

```
Student.executeQuery(
   'select s from Student s where s.type = :type order by s.university.name',
   [type : 'T'])
```

I like HQL and tend to use it a lot, but it couples you to Hibernate and relational databases - if you want to switch to a NoSQL database these queries will fail. Criteria queries, "where" queries and finders all use criteria queries internally, and those are converted to native query API calls by the GORM implementation.

The equivalent criteria queries would be

```
Student.withCriteria {
   eq 'type', 'T'
   order 'name', 'asc'
}
```

and

```
Student.withCriteria {
   eq 'type', 'T'
   university {
      order 'name', 'desc'
   }
}
```

Some unrelated notes:

You shouldn't use `id` in `equals` or `hashCode` calculations; if you have a persistent `Student` and a new non-persistent instance with the same name, type, and University, they should be considered equal, but since the non-persistent instance's id will be null they'll be considered different.

You don't need to specify the `id` property - Grails adds it and the `version` field to the bytecode via an AST transformation during compilation.

There's no need to map the column name of the `university` property to 'UNIVERSITY_ID' - that's what it would be anyway.

You can omit the redundant `column` setting in the `id` mapping.

Here's the Student class with cruft removed:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ['name', 'type', 'university'])
class Student {
   String name
   String type
   University university
}
```

and University:

```
class University {
   String name
   static mapping = {
      id generator: 'assigned'
   }
}
```